# "Failed to load url /src/main.jsx (resolved id: /src/main.jsx ). Does the file exist?" this error appears when I run the server

Tags: reactjs

I typed "npm run dev" to run the application but this error appears: "Failed to load url /src/main.jsx  (resolved id: /src/main.jsx ). Does the file exist?" and the page is white.
the code written in main.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

I tried restarting the vs code and the server but it doesn't work
I tried "npm i" but also it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please see [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) (tl;dr: **never**)

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same error because path to my project was too long.

Path to my project was `C:\Users\User\Documents\1 My Projects\C#\Complex\MyAwesomeProject API_REACT_DOCKER\ProfileWebApp`

I moved project to `C:\Users\User\Documents\MyAwesomeProject`

And it solved the issue.

Comment: This really sucks but it was the error for me too. I have to shorten it by a great amount.

Answer (score 3):

react app not able to find this **main.jsx** file.
Because your app path is not right or it will have some other character which is not identified or that app is not able to load.

SO make your app project short or simple, Be ensure that in your app file path there should not be these kind of symbols. e.g. #, *, _ , $, Etc.

I was facing the same error then i changed by app directory and after that i was able to start my app.

**You don't have to change anything else in code just change your app path or directory.**

[See Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iKTN.png)

Answer (score 2):

this happens when your change your **main.tsx** file to **main.jsx**

Go to your **index.html** file and there replace this

```
<script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
```

with this

```
<script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main.jsx file should be in the src folder, not the components folder.

Answer (score 1):

Match the **file name** that you are using in your **src folder**(index or main) and your root **index.html** file's script tag `<script src="./src/your-file-name.extension"></script>`.

For instance,

1. If in your src folder, the main file's name is ***main.jsx*** then, go to your root index.html file and replace the file name: `<script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

import './index.css'
delete this unused import

Comment: answer needs supporting information and seems to be an incorrect solution to the question

Answer (score 0):

Pay close attention to the path in the error. In my case, the path in the error didn't match what I had in my directory in VS Code (App vs app).

***Vite Error:*** "pre-transform error: failed to load url /src/**App/Layout**/index.tsx"

***VS Code:*** "/src/**app/layout**/index.tsx"

Updating the folder casing fixed the issue.